# Generate multiple classes with SCSS

Tags: sass, frontend

I want to have several classes for spacing like so:

```
.spacing-top-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.spacing-top-40 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.spacing-top-60{
  margin-top: 60px;
}

//and so on...
```

Is it possible to make SCSS somehow generate multiple very similar classes? I know this would be a nice case to use mixins, but then you would still write it down for every spacing you want to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@for` directive:

```
@for $i from 1 to 4 {
    .spacing-top-#{$i * 20} { margin-top: $i * 20px }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I was hoping something like this existed! This was what I was looking for and it works! Thank you! :)